# How to set cursor position in Android TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have quite a bit of information being displayed to the user in an app I am writing, however I have not found a solid working method to set the cursor to the bottom of the TextView so that they are not forced to "scroll" to get there.

Initially, there is little information being displayed, however as the user makes choices there is more and more data to display - with it being a necessity for the user to stop making inputs and scroll.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All other threads I have found revolve around setting the cursor position for EditText versus TextView.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I could think of is just go ahead and override the EditText widget and its painting so that you can adjust the background. And since I think its an extension of TextView you can go ahead and setEditable(false) so its not editable. Then you can also use the edittext features to set the cursor location stuff.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Considering the amount of data I am displaying, I simply elected to use TextView and set the gravity to bottom - the user can scroll up should they want to view a previous output.